# Precedencia de los operadores condicional ternario y asignación directa

Tags: c++

Estoy confundido respecto a la precedencia del operador de asignación directa y el operador condicional ternario:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int j, k;

    j = k = 0;
    (1 ? j : k) = 1; // primero
    printf("%d %d\n", j, k);

    j = k = 0;
    1 ? j : k = 1; // segundo
    printf("%d %d\n", j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Esperaba que la salida fuese:

```
1 0
1 0
```

Pero resulta ser:

```
1 0
0 0
```

Y recibo este aviso de compilación :

> main.cpp:20: warning: statement has no effect

Que es acerca de la línea comentada como segundo.

Dado que el operador de asignación tiene menos precedencia que el operador condicional ternario, esperaba que las líneas comentadas como primero y segundo fuesen equivalentes. Pero resulta que no.

Lo he intentado con g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010

*Esta pregunta es una traducción de [la original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499400/ternary-conditional-and-assignment-operator-precedence) que hice yo mismo.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La precedencia de operadores en los lenguajes C/C++ no está definida por una tabla o por números, sino por una gramática. Aquí esta la gramática para el operador condicional del [borrador de C++0x (en inglés)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) capítulo **5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]**:

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

Esta tabla de precedencia [tal y como estaba hace unos años](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/operator_precedence&oldid=5400) es por lo tanto correcta cuando se usa el operador de asignación al lado izquierdo de los dos puntos, pero no al usarlo al lado derecho. Cual es el motivo para esta asimetría no lo se. Puede que sea por razones históricas: en C el resultado condicional no era un lvalue, por lo que asignarle algo no tenía ningún sentido y permitir que se aceptase la asignación sin paréntesis puede haber parecido una buena idea en aquel entonces.
Hoy en día [esa tabla](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) ya está corregida y es correcta en todos los caso.

*Esta respuesta es una traducción de [la original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499583/956880) escrita por [Suma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16673/suma)*